# Вопрос о flask, воркерах и асинхронности

Tags: python, flask, очередь, redis

Есть приложение на flask у которого есть задачи (6 парсингов).
Каждый пользователь может самостоятельно загрузить нужные ему данные которые обрабатываются при помощи rq (база redis). Всё отлично работает, но меня беспокоит, что когда будет одновременно 30 запросов (учитывая что на один парсинг уходит от 10 секунд до 60) пользователи могут не дождаться ответов и просто уйти. Подскажите как поступать в таком случае, возможно очереди не удачный выбор или нужно добавить больше воркеров?

Comment: Отправь заголовки до начала расчёта и тогда браузер не сбросит коннект

Comment: @eri тогда пользователи быстро займут все web-воркеры и сайт просто перестанет отвечать.

Comment: Если воркер блокируется. На фласке давно не писал, на аиохттп на одном воркере можно открыть несколько десятков коннектов

Comment: Если не блокироваться, как на вэбсокетак, то почему должна забиться очередь?

Comment: @eri Flask синхронный и однопоточный. Представления должны завершать работу с максимально возможной скоростью и не должны ни в коем случае удерживать соединение.

Comment: И вэбсокетов нет? Стороннюю реализацию вэбсокет тогда прикрутить

Comment: @eri из коробки у Flask'а почти ничего нет, микрофреймворк же. Можно использовать Flask-SocketIO, тогда вместо поллинга сервера ajax-запросами, нужно будет просто слушать websocket. В остальном мой ответ не меняется.

Answer (score 1):

1. Получаете от пользователя данные;
2. Запускаете асинхронную задачу RQ с этими данными;
3. Отправляете пользователю идентификатор задачи;
4. На фронте показываете пользователю спиннер и с некоторым интервалом отправляете серверу ajax-запросы с идентификатором задачи;
5. Если задача не выполнена возвращаете соответствующий признак и фронт продолжает крутить спиннер;
6. Если задача выполнена, возвращаете результат работы и отображаете его на фронте.

Пример можно увидеть [здесь](https://testdriven.io/blog/asynchronous-tasks-with-flask-and-redis-queue/).

Comment: На данный момент у меня так всё и работает. Проблема в том что у воркера будут висеть постоянно предыдущие задачи выполняющиеся одна за одной.

Comment: Если нужно, чтобы задачи выполнялись быстрее, увеличивайте количество воркеров.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что хорошим решением было бы завести пул воркеров, которые занимаются парсингом, получая задания из rq и сохраняя его куда-то до тех пор, пока результат не будет запрошен пользователем. 
Оставьте постановку задач и выдачи конечных результатов фласку, а задачи парсинга - отдельной группе воркеров (которые можно разместить на отдельной машине с большим количеством процессоров). Таким образом, вам будет проще масштабировать вашу систему, а все фласк запросы будут реагировать достаточно быстро.